# PHP switch version 5.6 to 7 without using export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH

Tags: php

I use PHP 5.6.30 and I update into 7.20 but every time I open new terminal tab I've to switch version by using

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Is theier any way to use version 7 withour using this command line ?

Answer (score 1):

write the env var to `profile`:

```
vi /etc/profile
export PATH=/usr/local/php7/bin:$PATH

### then
php run.php
```

or

start script with `php7`:

```
/usr/local/php7/bin/php7 run.php
```

Comment: you mean I open terminal go to vi /etc/profile and add this  export PATH=/usr/local/php7/bin:$PATH then run php run.php right ?

Answer (score -1):

echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/php/cgi/7.3/bin/:$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin' >> .bashrc

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks